# Is there a native line break for Salesforce?

Tags: long-text-area, text, line-break

I'm having some text area fields that are populated via some external service via the API and also by the users who sometimes create new records, as well as changing existing ones. Via the API I can write all kinds of line break combinations (CRLF, CR, LF) to the fields "as is", while they will always be exported via the Data Loader as LF. But if I edit the record via the UI, the line breaks will be converted to CRLF - which will not happen via code (even if I directly modify that field). On top of that - all of them will be rendered as a line break in the UI in edit mode, while only CRLF and LF will be rendered as a line break on the record detail or if rendered via Visualforce.

This behavior feels so weird and inconsistent that I'm wondering if there's a "correct" way to save a line break in Salesforce or at least a native way. Something that I can rely on. As I'm doing some replacements afterwards (for historical reasons) this will really mess with my results.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's any official documentation outside of the Salesforce Apex Developer Guide that suggests what to use; all of the code examples in the documentation use `\n` (0x10/LF) exclusively (and `\t` for 0x09/tab). I've always used LF exclusively in any code I've written and never had a problem with it. I would say that's your best choice, unless you're specifically targeting a file format destined for legacy Windows/DOS apps that need CRLF (`\r\n`). When parsing any kind of input, I suggest converting CRLF to LF (it should be harmless to do so).